# MySQL linking table intersection query

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if my question sounds misleading, I'm not fully sure how to formulate it.

Consider the following tables: Fruit which has an ID and Name, Person which also has an ID and Name, and Person_has_Fruit (many to many linking table) which has a Person_ID and a Fruit_ID.

What transaction can retrieve the people which have two or more **specific** fruits? Basically how can I intersect the results?

Example:

Fruit table

```
ID | Name
-----------------
1  | Apple
2  | Pineapple
3  | Banana
4  | Lemon
```

Person table

```
ID | Name
-----------------
1  | Tom
2  | Bill
3  | John
```

Many to many table

```
PersonID | FruitID
-----------------
    3   |    1
    1   |    2
    3   |    2
    2   |    3
    3   |    3
```

I want a query to retrieve me John when I ask for the person which has Apple, Pineapple and Banana. Any suggestions?

I've tried 'SELECT * FROM Person_has_Fruit WHERE FruitID in ('1', '2', '3')' but that is incorrect as it retrieves all the person IDs which have one of them, so basically it implies an or relationship between the values.

Comment: have you tried to use group by + count + having?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return rows that have the same column values in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql)

Comment: Found this from Google, the definitive Stack Overflow question on this concept, intersection of tables/"relational division" is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to perform a relational division between the some tuples of `Fruit` table and the `Person` table.

So:

```
Select * From Person p
Where Not Exists ( Select * from Fruit f 
                   Where (Name = 'Apple' Or Name = 'Pinneapple' or Name = 'Banana')
                   And Not Exists ( Select * from Person_has_Fruit pf
                                    Where pf.PersonId = p.ID and pf.FruitId=f.ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try create a view first.

```
CREATE VIEW fruitowners AS 
( SELECT personfruit.personID, fruittable.id, persontable.person, fruittable.fruit
FROM persontable, fruittable, personfruit
WHERE personfruit.personID=persontable.id AND personfruit.fruitID=fruittable.id )
```

Then:

```
SELECT fruit FROM fruitowners
WHERE person='John'
```

returns all the fruit types John owns

And:

```
SELECT person FROM fruitowners
WHERE fruit='Banana'
```

returns all the banana owners.

And:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruitowners WHERE person='John'
```

returns the number of fruits John owns

And:

```
SELECT COUNT('fruit') FROM fruitowners WHERE person='John' and fruit='Banana'
```

returns how many bananas John owns

Comment: Your suggestion just allows to know which person has a certain type of fruits, or which fruit, a certain person has. With your answer, it's not possible to know if a person has 2 types of fruits without extra computation.

Comment: Yes the (SELECT fruit FROM fruitowners
WHERE person='John') returns all the fruit types john owns

Comment: It's true but than you have to check if (as on the example provided on the question: apple, pineapple, banana) certain fruits are on the returned rows.

Comment: Everything you said it's true. But the question is to discover which person has certain types of fruits. 

With your view, answer to the query "Which person has Pineapple and has Banana".

Comment: You mean like SELECT DISTINCT person FROM fruitowners
WHERE fruit='Banana' OR fruit='Pineapple' ? This would return the names of those who own those two fruit types

Comment: This will find persons that has banana or pineapple. If a person just have one, it will be caught by your query. It's suppose to retrieve Just the persons that have Both fruits, and not just one.

Comment: No! Replacing the OR by an AND, it's a Huge mistake, It's not possible for a row to have 2 values for the same attribute(column).