# extract customers with same hobbies with mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
customer id | hobby
```

I would like to use mysql query to extract customers which have the same hobbies.
If someone has more hobbies we have one row for each hobby.

It is easy to use

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customers
WHERE hobby='football'
```

My problem is that I want to search for two hobbies.

For example '`football`' and '`swimming`'  and the query must result only the customers which have both.

Is it possible to do it with query or should I use stored procedure and how ?

Comment: WHERE IN () GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(*) = number of items in IN()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return rows that have the same column values in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql)

Comment: Do you want customers who have *only* those two hobbies, or *at least* those two hobbies?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customers 
WHERE hobby in ('swimming','football')
group by custimer_id
having count(distinct hobby) = 2
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/528a45/2)

Comment: It seems to me extraordinarily unlikely that one customer can have the same hobby twice, but OK

Comment: Just to be sure, sure :)

Comment: (unless that hobby happens to be talking to oneself)

Comment: you select something different than you group by.

Comment: It works for me. See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/528a45/2). Your example data is weird though. I changed one value in my example.