# Query find value in comma seperated list mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

in my script a "restaurant" can have multiple locations so, i made a column in the restaurant table containing a coma seperated list with locations.

Now i want to make a msql query that checks if the id can be fount is this column (comma seperated list) and if so then select it. i came up with this

```
SELECT restaurant_id,restaurant_name 
FROM restaurant WHERE ('.$locIdList.') IN (locationRes) 
ORDER BY restaurant_name ASC'
```

It does work... but i have some restaurants where I added location 16 and 17 so (16,17) now when i do this query for location 16 it shows the restaurant but when i dot this for location 17 it does not... but the whole point was to get the multi values from the comma seperated list.

So how to do this ?

Comment: look at the "LIKE"-Keyword. And also for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: It would be best if you normalized your schema. Doing this with comma-separated lists is difficult and inefficient. Make a separate table of restaurant locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to create a relation table that implements the many-to-many relationship between restaurants and locations. Then you can use a solution like [How to return rows that have the same column values in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1) to find all the restaurants that are in all locations.

To search for a value in a comma-separated list, you use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). But this can only search for one value at a time. If you want to find restaurants that are in all locations, you need to combine multiple calls:

```
$locArray = explode(',', $locIdList);
$locQuery = implode(' AND ', array_map(function($loc) { return "FIND_IN_SET($loc, locationRes)"; }, $locArray));
$query = "SELECT restaurant_id,restaurant_name 
          FROM restaurant 
          WHERE $locQuery
          ORDER BY restaurant_name ASC";
```

If you want to find restaurants that are in *any* of the locations instead of all locations, change `AND` to `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid putting multiple values inside a single column.

Instead, it's recommended to create another table `locations(location_id, col1, col2, restaurant_id)`, while the `restaurant_id` field references to the primary key in table `restaurant`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a comma separated list you are pulling from a database, you could use PHP to separate the list and create an array of each item.

```
$result_of_sql = "restaurant 1, restaurant 2, restaurant 3, restaurant 4, restaurant 5, restaurant 6";

$restaurants = explode(',', $result_of_sql);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($restaurants as $restaurant) {
  echo '<li>' . trim($restaurant) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

What happens here is first, you pull out all of you restaurants (the comma separated list). Then you use `explode` to take away the commas and create an array. Then you use the `foreach` loop to echo the entire array out. `trim` is just to clean everything up by removing whitespace you might have before and after the restaurant name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to generate the query for each comma-delimited value. i.e., run a PHP loop on comma-delimited comparison string, convert it into individual items and compare each item through LIKE Operator and an IN () function.

```
SELECT restaurant_id,restaurant_name 
FROM restaurant WHERE ('16') IN (locationRes) 
OR 
FROM restaurant WHERE ('17') IN (locationRes) 
ORDER BY restaurant_name ASC'
```