# Filter by multiple items with join between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `posts` like that:

[image]

and another table `post_filters` in witch I have stored the filter for each post:

[image]

where:

[image]

[image]

I want all the `apples` with

- `color` `red` or `Yellow` and
- from the `country` `England` and `France`.

How can I do that with join between `posts` and `posts_filters`? It is possible to do only one join between the two tables ?

I've tried something like that:

```
SELECT   
    posts.*,    
    a1.*,  
    a2.*  
FROM posts  
    LEFT JOIN post_filters a1 ON posts.ID=a1.post_id AND a1.filter_id=1   
    LEFT JOIN post_filters a2 ON posts.ID=a2.post_id AND a2.filter_id=2      
WHERE   
a1.selected_filter_item IN (2,3)   
AND   
a2.selected_filter_item IN (1,3)
```

It doesn't work proprierly and I would like to have only ONE join.

Comment: Do it in steps. How do you find apples with a specific color? Or two colors? Etc.

Comment: When you use `IN (...)` you get an `OR` condition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1 for how to do `AND` for the countries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   
    p.*, 
    f.*,  
    fi.*  
FROM posts p
    JOIN post_filters pf ON pf.post_id = p.ID
    JOIN filters f ON f.filter_id = pf.filter_id   
    JOIN filters_items fi ON fi.filters_item = pf.selected_filter_item AND fi.filter_id = f.filter_id     
WHERE
f.filter_name IN ('country','color') AND
fi.filter_item_name IN ('England','France','red','yellow')
```

Try this query