# How can I check for "duplicates" through another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have 3 tables:

- `collections` (`id`, `name`)
- `items` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `price`)
- `collection_items` (`id`, `collection_id`, `item_id`, `order`)

Users can create their own `collections` from a list of `items` but I need a way to check whether a `collection` with all those `items` (in that same `order`) already exists - to prevent duplicates.

This is what I was trying before I realised it was not going to work..

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    collections
WHERE
    collections.id IN(
        SELECT
            c.id
        FROM
            collections c
        JOIN
            collection_items ci ON c.id = ci.collection_id
        WHERE
            (ci.order = 1 AND ci.item_id = 75) OR (ci.order = 2 AND ci.item_id = 58)
    )
```

How can I return any collections that have certain ids in a specific order?

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question a few hours ago? I closed it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1

Comment: Yes I did but your "duplicate" didn't help me at all :( I'm not trying to sum anything up

Comment: The duplicate has nothing to do with summing something up. It uses summing as part of the way to detect if all the rows are there.

Comment: Yes that's my bad I was under the impression that question was trying to sum up a score from a few different ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to the solutions in [How to return rows that have the same column values in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1)

```
SELECT ci.collection_id
FROM collection_items ci
WHERE
    (ci.order = 1 AND ci.item_id = 75) OR (ci.order = 2 AND ci.item_id = 58)
GROUP BY ci.collection_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

If this returns a row, it means there's a duplicate.

The number in the `HAVING` clause should be the number of items you're checking for you have in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I don't think you need a join. You can get rid of collections table and use ci.collection_id instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to look into collections - just look into collection items like:

```
select collection_id from collection_items ci
WHERE (ci.order = 1 AND ci.item_id = 75) 
AND (ci.order = 2 AND ci.item_id = 58)
AND 2 = (select count(*) from collection_items innter_ci 
         where innter_ci.collection_id = ci.collection_id)
```

If you don't care if the collection_item has the same number of items, then you don't need the last "AND"