# EXISTS Sintaxe - MySQL - Doesn't filter for register not in both queries

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

```
SELECT
    sys.tbl_unidades.nome_unidade 'name',
    sys.tbl_unidades.id_unidade 'value'
FROM
    sys.tbl_unidades,
    sys.tbl_unidades_contratos
WHERE
    sys.tbl_unidades.id_unidade = sys.tbl_unidades_contratos.id_unidade
    AND sys.tbl_unidades.dt_fim IS NULL
    AND sys.tbl_unidades_contratos.id_contrato = 10

    AND EXISTS 

        (SELECT
            sys.tbl_unidades.nome_unidade 'name',
            sys.tbl_unidades.id_unidade 'value'
        FROM
            sys.tbl_unidades,
            sys.tbl_unidades_contratos
        WHERE
            sys.tbl_unidades.id_unidade = sys.tbl_unidades_contratos.id_unidade
            AND sys.tbl_unidades.dt_fim IS NULL
            AND sys.tbl_unidades_contratos.id_contrato =11)
```

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to solve before posting any code.. go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for getting more help from the community

Comment: Please learn to user ANSI JOIN syntax instead of archaic cross product.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery in `EXISTS` is not correlated to the main query. So it's just checking whether the subquery returns any rows, not that they have the same `nome_unidade` and `id_unidade` as the main query.

```
SELECT
    u1.nome_unidade 'name',
    u1.id_unidade 'value'
FROM
    sys.tbl_unidades AS u1
JOIN 
    sys.tbl_unidades_contratos AS c1
ON u1.id_unidade = c1.id_unidade
WHERE
    u1.dt_fim IS NULL
    AND c1.id_contrato = 10

    AND EXISTS 

        (SELECT 1                
        FROM
            sys.tbl_unidades AS u2
        JOIN
            sys.tbl_unidades_contratos AS c2
        ON u2.id_unidade = c2.id_unidade
        WHERE
            u2.dt_fim IS NULL
            AND c2.id_contrato = 11
            AND u2.id_unidade = u1.id_unidade)
```

I suspect you don't really need both tables in the subquery, you just need to check `tbl_unidades_contratos`.

Also see [How to return rows that have the same column values in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1) for other ways to find the IDs that have all of several values in a column.

Comment: Barmar nailed it again. +10.

Comment: Many thanks for replies! But it havent worked yet. I havent got what you mean with the tables are not correlated. They are essentialy the same query, but with another parameters.

Comment: A correlated subquery has to contain something in its `WHERE` clause that relates the rows selected in the subquery to the row in the main query. That's what `AND u2.id_unidade = u1.id_unidade` does.

Comment: @GustavoCarvalheira See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: The id_unidade must  come from tbl_matmed_codigos table. The join with tbl_unidades only exists because of the dt_fim that is a kind of expiration date. I tried to use both id_unidade and id_contrato from the main table mc1 (tbl_matmed_codigos from the first query) and mc2 (same table from query 2). It hasn't worked out.

Comment: There's no `tbl_matmed_codigos` anywhere in the question.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I am having the same problem with another group of tables, but the same issue. I can send you through my email. I have the same requirement in two different  parts of the development, and as I had this issue in the first, I tried to make the same with the second.

Comment: Can you add sample data and the expected result to the question? It would be even better if you made a sqlfiddle with the data to save me the work.

Comment: Yes, I tried it before, but the field doesn't support such a size of string. I will try again.

Comment: SELECT  distinct
   mc1.id_tipo_codigo value 
        FROM 
   sys.tbl_matmed_codigos AS mc1

  JOIN sys.tbl_matmed_tipos_codigos AS mtc1 ON mc1.id_tipo_codigo = mtc1.id_matmed_tipo_codigo
        JOIN tbl_unidades AS mu1 ON mc1.id_unidade = mu1.id_unidade
  JOIN tbl_unidades AS mu11 ON mc1.id_unidade = mu11.id_unidade 

  WHERE
   mu1.dt_fim is null 
            and mc1.id_contrato = 10 
            and mc1.id_unidade = 3

           AND  EXISTS

Comment: (SELECT
     mc2.id_tipo_codigo value 
    FROM 
     sys.tbl_matmed_codigos AS mc2

    JOIN sys.tbl_matmed_tipos_codigos AS mtc2 ON mc2.id_tipo_codigo = mtc2.id_matmed_tipo_codigo
    JOIN sys.tbl_unidades AS mu2 ON mc2.id_unidade = mu2.id_unidade
    JOIN sys.tbl_unidades AS mu22 ON mc2.id_unidade = mu22.id_unidade 

    WHERE
     mu2.dt_fim is null 
     and mc2.id_contrato = 11 
     and mc2.id_unidade = 4
                    and mc2.id_unidade = mc1.id_unidade
                    and mc2.id_contrato = mc1.id_contrato)

Comment: I don't understand what this added code is supposed to mean. I asked for sample table contents and the desired result.

Comment: Thats the whole query. Its is returning both 1 and 3 codes, but it is supposed to return only 3, that occurs in both queries.

Comment: Just to go simple. I have two tables with just one column, One that returns two rows with the id 3 as results and another table also with only one column and results 1 and 3 in two rows. I need to have the intersection of these two table. It means a results with only one row with the data of 3. Ok?

Comment: Doesn't the question I linked to show exactly how to get that?

Comment: I got it! Just included and "mc4.id_tipo_codigo = mc1.id_tipo_codigo" relating the query row with the first query row, for each of the EXISTS clauses. It worked.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and sorry about the bunch of codes!