# php pdo property array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

```
---property---
id | ozellik
1  | "random"
2  | "fast"
3  | "red"
-----------

----property_cafe--------
id | cafe_id | property_id
1  | 1       |  1   
2  | 1       |  2
3  | 1       |  3
-----------------------

---cafe---
id | name
1  | lorem
-----------------

property.id = property_cafe.property_id
cafe.id = property_cafe.cafe_id
```

Checkbox select 1,2,3. I want to see the feature of cafes with the feature of 1,2,3 id.

I can create a separate query, but I have unlimited feature table close to 100, I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the query with `WHERE property.id IN (?, ?, ?, ...)`, where you build the list of question marks dynamically from the size of the array of checkbox values.

```
$where_count = count($_POST['property']);
$questions = '?' . str_repeat(', ?', $where_count-1);
$sql = "SELECT c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(p.ozellik) AS ozellik
        FROM cafe AS c
        JOIN property_cafe AS pc ON pc.cafe_id = c.id
        JOIN property AS p ON pc.property_id = p.id
        WHERE p.id IN ($questions)
        GROUP BY c.id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$params = $_POST['property']; 
$params[] = $where_count;
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Passing an array to `$stmt->execute()` uses the elements to fill in the `?` placeholders in the SQL.

See [How to return rows that have the same column values in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1) for various ways to write a query to find all the cafes that have all the properties. This is the simplest for making this dynamic SQL.

This assumes your checkboxes are written like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="property[]" value="1"> Random
<input type="checkbox" name="property[]" value="2"> Fast
<input type="checkbox" name="property[]" value="3"> Red
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uECKMjFp6z8gtJH26BALUy/0)

Comment: IN ($questions) = or , me and need
it has to be 3

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's as many values as the user selected from the checkboxes named `property[]`.

Comment: have all , the result should be select 1,2,3 property  = cafe id 1

Comment: Oh, you want to get the cafes that have *all* the properties?

Comment: çalışıyor sağolun deniyorum şuan

Comment: I've added a db-fiddle demo, it returns more than one result for me.