# MySQL where with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

Table **events**

```
|  PkID  |  StartDate  |   Title  |
|    1   | 2020-08-21  | Event #1 |
|    2   | 2020-08-21  | Event #2 |
|    3   | 2020-08-22  | Event #3 |
```

Table **eventcategories**

```
|  EventID  | CategoryID |
|     1     |     40     |
|     1     |    144     |
|     2     |    144     |
|     3     |     40     |
|     3     |    146     |
```

I want to display events which have category 40 and categories 144 or 146.

In my example Event #1 and Event #3

I try

```
SELECT e.Title
        FROM events e
            LEFT JOIN eventcategories ec ON (ec.EventID = e.PkID)
        WHERE ec.CategoryID = 40 AND ec.CategoryID IN (144,146) AND e.StartDate >= "2020-08-07"
```

but no results

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with an `INNER` join and setting the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT e.Title
FROM events e INNER JOIN eventcategories ec 
ON ec.EventID = e.PkID
WHERE ec.CategoryID IN (40, 144, 146) AND e.StartDate >= '2020-08-07'
GROUP BY e.PkID, e.Title
HAVING SUM(ec.CategoryID = 40) 
   AND MAX(ec.CategoryID) IN (144, 146)
```

The above `HAVING` clause may work for your sample data but it may not be scalable.
Another, more general option would be:

```
HAVING SUM(ec.CategoryID = 40) 
   AND SUM(ec.CategoryID IN (144, 146))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=171dd829d77bf3c5b348f0ed7ff02581).
Results:

```
> | Title    |
> | :------- |
> | Event #1 |
> | Event #3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The *where* condition is applied row wise. So for any one row your both conditions: *ec.CategoryID = 40 AND ec.CategoryID IN (144,146)* cannot be true simultaneously. This is the reason your query is not working

I see this approach working:

1. Fetch event ids from eventcategories where category id = 40
2. Fetch event ids from eventcategories where category id in (144,146)
3. Inner Join 1 and 2 to get event ids that satisfy both
4. Join with events to get Title

Comment: Could just combine all the possible categories in the IN: WHERE ec.CategoryID IN (40, 144,146).

Or use an OR: WHERE e.StartDate >= "2020-08-07" AND (ec.CategoryID = 40 OR ec.CategoryID IN (144,146))

Comment: That would be incorrect as it would include EventId 2 in the resultset but the expected result set contains EventId 1 and 3 only.