# How to check for duplicates in a 1 to many table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a system which stores peoples outfits. Each outfit contains 1 to many items.

Thus my tables are like this

```
outfits
+-----------+--------+
| outfit_id | cus_id |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      5 |
|         2 |     92 |
+-----------+--------+

items
+---------+-------+-------+
| item_id | name  |  sku  |
+---------+-------+-------+
|       1 | hat   |  1111 |
|       2 | pants |  2222 |
|       3 | shirt |  3333 |
|       4 | shoes |  4444 |
+---------+-------+-------+

items_in_outfit
+--------+-----------+---------+
| ino_id | outfit_id | item_id |
+--------+-----------+---------+
|      1 |         1 |       3 |
|      2 |         1 |       2 |
|      3 |         1 |       4 |
|      4 |         2 |       1 |
|      4 |         2 |       3 |
+--------+-----------+---------+
```

I am given this information:

- `cus_id=92` wants to create another outfit with the `sku`'s `1111` and `3333`

However, this is a duplicate of `outfit_id=2`. So I want mysql to return me the `outfit_id` of 2. If its not a duplicate, return nothing. It only counts as a duplicate if the **same** `cus_id` is trying to make an outfit which has the **exact same** `sku`'s already.

If `cus_id=5` wants to create another outfit with the `sku`'s `1111` and `3333`. It should return nothing (as its not a duplicate) because `cus_id=5` doesn't have an outfit with just `1111` and `3333`

```
SELECT o.outfit_id FROM
outfits o JOIN
items_in_outfit iio
ON o.outfit_id = iio.outfit_id JOIN
items i
ON iio.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE cus_id = 92 AND ...
```

Comment: Is this a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)?

Comment: @Barmar No. This is my own project. I saw mysql cannot make unique keys in 1 to many relationships. My attempt at this is in PHP, which its so slow because I concat the SKU's into a string and check if the string is the same string as the sku's provided to me. I am not sure on how to do this as its a 1 to many relationship

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1

Comment: @Barmar this is a 1 to many relationship table. Doing it with a 1 to 1 table is easier, which I understand.

Comment: How are you driving this - is it a stored proc? How are you passing in the SKU's? Or are they written into a request table?

Comment: I essentially using PHP and concat to the SQL statement. For example `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE sku = ... or sku = ...`. I am concatenating `sku = ...` to the sql statement. So basically if I understand how to find an outfit with 2 items, I can just contcat the same sku's over and over to the sql statement for multiple sku's

Comment: After you join the tables you have a 1-to-many relationship that you can use the solutions in that question to solve.

Comment: @Barmar Okay. I join the tables, but now I have multiple rows. I might have multiple different outfits from the same user. How do i figure out if its a duplicate. I don't understand how that question solves my question yet

Comment: `AND sku IN (1111, 3333) GROUP BY o.outfit_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you achieve what you are looking for :

```
select 
  cus_id 
from(
  select 
    cus_id, 
    group_concat(sku order by sku asc) as items
  from outfits o
  join items_in_outfit iio on o.outfit_id = iio.outfit_id
  join items i on iio.item_id = i.item_id
  group by cus_id
) T
where items = '1111,3333'
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0aa04ec6b0c7abc976f28c0fa958bf4a)

**EDIT** : As an outfit can't contain more than 1 instance of the same item, this solution may be better for you as you don't have to order the sku id in your php before :

```
select 
  o.outfit_id
from 
  outfits o
  join items_in_outfit iio on o.outfit_id = iio.outfit_id
  join items i on iio.item_id = i.item_id
where sku IN (1111, 3333) 
group by o.outfit_id having COUNT(*) = 2
```

[**SEE SECOND DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ae08ded5ea8632f648aec4c42a7180a0)

Comment: Yes of course, just concat them in the right order in your php

Comment: Oh true. You can do that too

Comment: Also there may be a better solution as barmar said, however it depends on one thing, can an outfit_id have the same item_id multiple times ?

Comment: No. For example and `outfit_id` can only have 1 instance of an `item_id`. So this outfit is NOT possible `1111,1111,3333`. However, this `outfit_id` IS possible, `1111,3333`. Is there a better solution?

Comment: See my edit above, this may be a little better for your case