# Why doesn't my MySql-Query work the way I would like it to work?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, subquery

I have a MySQL-DB which has three tables: drugs, ingredients (both have a m:n relationship) and a linking table/association table. So obviously a drug can have multiple ingredients and ingredients are allowed to be in multiple drugs. I wanna create a website, where my user can select <=3 ingredients he wanna have in his drug and <=3 ingredients he don't wanna have. Therefore I created a stored procedure:

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `getMeds`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `epharmacy`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getMeds` (IN all1 VARCHAR(10), IN all2 VARCHAR(10), IN all3 VARCHAR(10), 
                            IN unall1 VARCHAR(10), IN unall2 VARCHAR(10), IN unall3 VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
SELECT m_id, m_name, i_id, i_name FROM epharmacy.`mi_med-ing` INNER JOIN epharmacy.`m_medication` 
INNER JOIN epharmacy.`i_ingredients` 
ON mi_m_id = m_id AND mi_i_id = i_id

#Allowed
WHERE (i_id = all1 OR all1 = '') 
AND (i_id = all2 OR all2 = '')
AND (i_id = all3 OR all3 = '') 

#Unallowed
AND ((i_id!= unall1 OR unall1 = '') 
AND (i_id != unall2 OR unall2 = '') 
AND (i_id != unall3 OR unall3 = ''))

ORDER BY m_id ASC;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

call getMeds('I005', 'I006', 'I007', 'I001', 'I002', 'I003');
```

But this somehow doesn't work. I should get two drugs in return, but I don't get anything. I tried many things, like subsqueries and other JOINS, but it didn't help. Hope you can :)

Edit:
That's how my DB looks like:
m_medication:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_medication` (
  `m_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `m_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`m_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `m_medication` (`m_id`, `m_name`) VALUES('M00001', 'drug1');
INSERT INTO `m_medication` (`m_id`, `m_name`) VALUES('M00002', 'drug2');
```

i_ingredients:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `i_ingredients` (
  `i_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `i_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`i_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `i_ingredients` (`i_id`, `i_name`) VALUES('I005', 'ingredient1');
INSERT INTO `i_ingredients` (`i_id`, `i_name`) VALUES('I006', 'ingredient2');
INSERT INTO `i_ingredients` (`i_id`, `i_name`) VALUES('I007', 'ingredient3');
```

mi_med-ing:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mi_med-ing` (
  `mi_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `mi_i_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mi_m_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mi_id`),
  KEY `mi_i_id` (`mi_i_id`),
  KEY `mi_m_id` (`mi_m_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO mi_med-ing (mi_id, mi_i_id, mi_m_id) VALUES('MI001', 'I005', 'M00001'); 
INSERT INTO mi_med-ing (mi_id, mi_i_id, mi_m_id) VALUES('MI002', 'I006', 'M00001'); 
INSERT INTO mi_med-ing (mi_id, mi_i_id, mi_m_id) VALUES('MI003', 'I007', 'M00001'); 
INSERT INTO mi_med-ing (mi_id, mi_i_id, mi_m_id) VALUES('MI004', 'I005', 'M00002'); 
INSERT INTO mi_med-ing (mi_id, mi_i_id, mi_m_id) VALUES('MI005', 'I006', 'M00002'); 
INSERT INTO mi_med-ing (mi_id, mi_i_id, mi_m_id) VALUES('MI006', 'I007', 'M00002');
```

Foreign Keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `mi_med-ing`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `mi_med-ing_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mi_i_id`) REFERENCES `i_ingredients` (`i_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `mi_med-ing_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`mi_m_id`) REFERENCES `m_medication` (`m_id`);
```

Comment: Gonnae add sample data and expected output neebs..

Comment: You're trying to match multiple ingredient IDs in the same row, not grouping the rows by drug.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1 for how to get the drugs with all the ingredients in the set.

Comment: Then use `NOT IN` to filter out the unwanted drugs

Comment: @P.Salmon I have some, that's why I am expecting two results.

Comment: @Barmar I tried it, I put a GROUP BY m_id before the 'WHERE clause' and replaced after that the 'WHERE' clause with 'HAVING'. It still doesn't work. Could you write the code down please?

Comment: Using a minus sign in a name is a very bad idea. It forces you to escape the table name with backticks every time you use it. `INSERT INTO mi_med-ing ...` is wrong for example. It mus be `INSERT INTO \`mi_med-ing\` ...`. I suggest you change the table name to `mi_med_ing`.

Answer (score 0):

To find all the medicines that have all the required ingredients, you need to perform a grouped query in the join table; see [How to return rows that have the same column values in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1).

To exclude the unallowed ingredients, use a subquery that returns any medicines that have any of these ingredients, and then use `m_id NOT IN (subquery)` to filter them out.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getMeds` (IN all1 VARCHAR(10), IN all2 VARCHAR(10), IN all3 VARCHAR(10), 
                            IN unall1 VARCHAR(10), IN unall2 VARCHAR(10), IN unall3 VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE all_count INT DEFAULT (all1 != '') + (all2 != '') + (all3 != '');
SELECT m_id, m_name, i_id, i_name
FROM (SELECT mi_m_id
      FROM `mi_med-ing`
      WHERE mi_i_id IN (all1, all2, all3)
      GROUP BY mi_m_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = all_count) AS a
INNER JOIN `mi_med-ing` AS mi ON mi.mi_m_id = a.mi_m_id
INNER JOIN `m_medication` ON mi.mi_m_id = m_id
INNER JOIN `i_ingredients` ON mi.mi_i_id = i_id
WHERE m_id NOT IN (
    SELECT mi_m_id
    FROM `mi_med-ing`
    WHERE mi_i_id IN (unall1, unall2, unall3)
)
ORDER BY m_id ASC;
END
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for the first SELECT. It says that "SELECT" isn't valid in that position.

Comment: Make sure you have `;` at the end of the `DECLARE` line.

Comment: If you search for other questions with that error message, it's usually due to a missing delimiter.

Comment: I just edited the parentheses in the `DEFAULT` value, I think my previous version had incorrect precedence.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the DECLARE line, since I don't get any errors when I remove the SELECT. However I searched for missing parantheses in the SELECT statement but couldn't find any.

Comment: Obviously you don't get an error saying SELECT is invalid if you remove SELECT. But the reason is usually that you didn't end something properly *before* it, so you can't start a SELECT there.

Comment: I found another error: `all` is a keyword, so I couldn't use it as an alias. After fixing, I tested and I don't get any syntax errors.

Comment: Yes I tried it, the syntax error is gone, but I still don't get any results(?)

Comment: Can you add sample data to the question, or create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: INSERT INTO `mi_med-ing` (`mi_id`, `mi_i_id`, `mi_m_id`) VALUES('MI001', 'I001', 'M00001');
INSERT INTO `mi_med-ing` (`mi_id`, `mi_i_id`, `mi_m_id`) VALUES('MI002', 'I002', 'M00001');
INSERT INTO `mi_med-ing` (`mi_id`, `mi_i_id`, `mi_m_id`) VALUES('MI003', 'I003', 'M00001');
INSERT INTO `mi_med-ing` (`mi_id`, `mi_i_id`, `mi_m_id`) VALUES('MI004', 'I001', 'M00002');
INSERT INTO `mi_med-ing` (`mi_id`, `mi_i_id`, `mi_m_id`) VALUES('MI005', 'I002', 'M00002');
INSERT INTO `mi_med-ing` (`mi_id`, `mi_i_id`, `mi_m_id`) VALUES('MI006', 'I003', 'M00002');

Comment: Put it into the question.

Comment: Sample data for all 3 tables.

Comment: Ok, I added it to my question.

Comment: I tested it and fixed a few mistakes, try it now.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have any of the required ingredients in the call.

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong data. I corrected it now, it does have the right data know, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried your query with the updated data. It returns all the drugs because none of them have any of the ingredients `I001`, `I002`, or `I003`.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7182c29c6ec87f7a6b3d758cfc5c055d

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. That solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three tables:

- m_medication = drug
- i_ingredients = ingedient
- mi_med-ing = bridge table for their m:n relation

You want to return drugs with all their ingredients, where the following applies for the drug:

- all desired ingredients are in the drug
- no undesired ingredients are in the drug

Two steps:

1. Aggregate the bridge table per drug to find all drugs that fulfill all the requirements.
2. Select all thus found drugs and their ingredients.

The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getMeds (IN all1 VARCHAR(10), IN all2 VARCHAR(10), IN all3 VARCHAR(10), 
                          IN unall1 VARCHAR(10), IN unall2 VARCHAR(10), IN unall3 VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
  SELECT m.*, i.*
  FROM epharmacy.m_medication m
  JOIN epharmacy.`mi_med-ing` mi ON mi.mi_m_id = m.m_id
  JOIN epharmacy.i_ingredients i ON i.i_id = mi.mi_i_id
  WHERE m.m_id IN
  (
    SELECT mi_m_id
    FROM epharmacy.`mi_med-ing`
    GROUP BY mi_m_id
    HAVING (all1   = '' OR SUM(mi_i_id = all1)   > 0)
       AND (all2   = '' OR SUM(mi_i_id = all2)   > 0)
       AND (all3   = '' OR SUM(mi_i_id = all3)   > 0)
       AND (unall1 = '' OR SUM(mi_i_id = unall1) = 0)
       AND (unall2 = '' OR SUM(mi_i_id = unall2) = 0)
       AND (unall3 = '' OR SUM(mi_i_id = unall3) = 0)
  )
  ORDER BY m.m_id, i.i_id;
END
```

How the aggregation works: In MySQL true = 1 and false = 0. I add up boolean expressions and hence get 0 when there is no match at all or > 0 when there is a match in the group.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e623f39daac369e3ac58ff1b18d992b