# MySQL query for selecting distinct rows with all possible values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my DB table named 'test_tbl':

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | D |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | D |

Here every 'id' can have at most 4 possible values (A,B,C,D) for 'type' column. I want to find out those ids who don't have all four values in 'type' column. So my expected output should be ids (3,4). I have tried as following:

```
select DISTINCT id
from test_tbl
where id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id FROM test_tbl 
    where
    type='A' and type='B' and type='C' and type='D');
```

But this is giving output all the ids from table.

Comment: How can the subquery return anything? How could a single row have 4 different types?

Comment: Select stuff group by something having count(distinct something) < some value

Comment: To understand how to write the subquery correctly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1

Comment: @FrankBlack78 nice work! can you please rewrite that for mysql? Moreover I have some other values too for type column and every id can have same type value multiple times. I have edited the DB file in your link.

Comment: I can't see your edits. You have to post your own Link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select id
from test_tbl
group by id
having count(distinct type) <> 4;
```

If you can have types other than A, B, C, and D, then add:

```
where type in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```