# Is there a better way to optmize a mysql where clause with multiple IN & AND statements

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Given a list of ProductID numbers, I need to find details on invoices that contain ALL of the listed ProductID numbers.  The number of items in the list is dynamic. Tables look something like this.

### Products

ProductID
ProductName

### Invoices

InvoiceID
DateOrdered
CustomerID

### Invoice_Products

QTY
ProductID
InvoiceID

Right now I have working MySQL SQL statement but I think performance may become an issue.  I wasnt sure if there was a better way to write this:

```
Select InvoiceId, DateOrdered, CustomerID
from Invoices
where InvoiceID in (
     select InvoiceID from Invoice_Products where ProductID = 5
)
AND 
InvoiceID in (
     select InvoiceID from Invoice_Products where ProductID = 100
)
AND
InvoiceID in (
     select InvoiceID from Invoice_Products where ProductID = 1005
)
```

My Product List will be provided by a multiple select box of products.  Only invoices with all items matched should be displayed else I would have just done an inner join with an in statement.

Comment: Use WHERE EXISTS instead of WHERE IN.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, `JOIN` is almost always better than `IN subquery`.

And you can get all the invoice IDs in a single query.

```
SELECT i.InvoiceId, i.DateOrdered, i.CustomerID
FROM Invoices i
JOIN (
    SELECT InvoiceID
    FROM Invoice_Products
    WHERE ProductID IN (5, 100, 1005)
    GROUP BY InvoiceID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) = 3
) AS ip ON i.InvoiceID = ip.InvoiceID
```

See [How to return rows that have the same column values in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1) for an explanation of the subquery.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) = 3`, not `==`